# how can i write this sql according to the following criteria

Tags: sql

```
SELECT TestName,
    SUM(TestFee) AS TestFee ,
    COUNT(*) "No of Tests"
    FROM  ALLPATIENTINFO 
    WHERE ReqDate BETWEEN '2016-11-04' AND '2016-11-05'
    GROUP BY  TestName
```

Here  only shows Testname ,total,and count number accoroding to the date .but i want to show all of the testName whose are saved in data table. if the test name out of this date then it only shows testname and testfee & count no will be zero.

Comment: Update your question adn show a proper data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option here is to move the logic of the `WHERE` clause into the `SELECT` clause and use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT TestName,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ReqDate BETWEEN '2016-11-04' AND '2016-11-05'
                THEN TestFee ELSE 0 END) AS TestFee,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ReqDate BETWEEN '2016-11-04' AND '2016-11-05'
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "No of Tests in Range",
       COUNT(*) AS "Total No of Test"
FROM ALLPATIENTINFO
GROUP BY TestName
```

This will guarantee that every test name which appears in your original data set will also appear in the result set.

Comment: but there is a problem. It not shows sum between the common testName and i want to show the actual count number instead of "  1 "

Comment: @sufianahmed Then retain `COUNT(*)` which you originally had.  See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT TestName,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ReqDate BETWEEN '2016-11-04' AND '2016-11-05' THEN TestFee ELSE 0 END) AS TestFee ,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ReqDate BETWEEN '2016-11-04' AND '2016-11-05' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "No of Tests"
FROM  ALLPATIENTINFO 
GROUP BY  TestName;
```

If you have a separate table with all the tests lists, you can use a `LEFT JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT t.TestName, SUM(TestFee) AS TestFee ,
       COUNT(api.testname) "No of Tests"
FROM TESTS t LEFT JOIN
     ALLPATIENTINFO api
     ON t.testname = api.testname AND
        api.ReqDate BETWEEN '2016-11-04' AND '2016-11-05'
GROUP BY t.TestName;
```

This may be a better solution, because it will include all tests, even those that have never been done.

Comment: but there is a problem. It not shows sum between the common testName and i want to show the actual count number instead of "  1 "

Comment: @sufianahmed . . . It took me a while to understand your comment.  The `count()` in the first subquery should have been `sum()`.